# Bluetooth Pairing? Driving me nuts

Tags: bluetooth-pairing

Can someone hack into my phone and wifi from connecting to my Bluetooth. How could someone see what I am typing or what site I am on. And then erase's everything and uninstall my apps.

Comment: The chances of getting opinionated answers are quite high here (we don't really deal with offensive security here). You're better off asking the question on [security.se]. Make sure you follow their [on-topic](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and question-quality guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Nop, hacking into an android isn't that easy unless you nonsensically provide `root` permissions (for which your phone must be rooted).

I create a keyboard app, you press on key of my keyboard app, I log your key. As simple as that. Or I make an application which has a service secretly running in background and capturing all your keystrokes.

Again, the app can erase your internal memory's data (although for it to affect system, it needs `root` permission, same for uninstalling apps without any prompt).

And one thing, I have never seen android getting hacked to that level with just bluetooth pairing, nop. Even if someone tries to use some service, you would definitely get some sort of prompt.

The only time this could happen is if you install some really bad app (from some untrusted source and such, and give it `root` permissions without understanding purpose for that app (which is time you are doomed)).

**So what you should do?**

Simply install apps from play store. Almost nothing as trusted as that. And even before installing from play store, read `permissions` required by that app correctly. This is where you can catch most malicious apps (although google also has its own not-very-effective-but-still-better-than-nothing malware detection system). And lastly, be extra careful with root permissions.

Remember, **Android is as secure as your common sense**.

Ofcourse there are those great threats like `stagefright` and such, but you don't really have to worry that much, just make sure you keep yourself updated with google. If your phone doesn't have enough updates, then its most likely going to be fine, just keep up with your common sense.